# Order of picked up meta tags in the html-head

Tags: html, wordpress, meta-tags, html-head

I was wondering if someone could explain how social media rich previews define which `og:title` to pick.

I use wordpress and for certain pages I insert php echo strings to inject them into the `<head>`. I choose to do that to change certain titles and descriptions into more commercial texts. What obvisouly happens is that there are 2 `og:title` meta tags; my injected one and the Wordpress backend page title.

Once I was told that the first meta tag in the top of the `<head>` will be picked as thé meta tag to be picked up for rich previews for example, but this seems not to happen (anymore).

Below is my current situation and exact order of meta tags in the `<head>`:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title> // my injected and used by Google
  <link rel="canonical" content="https://example.com">
  <meta name="description" content="description">
  <meta name="subject" content="example">
  <meta name="og:image" content="/image.jpg"> // my injected and used by Social Media
  <meta property="og:title" content="og:title #1"> // my injected og:title, but ignored
  <meta property="og:description" content="description">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="EXAMPLE">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="description">
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com" hreflang="nl-nl">
  <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com" hreflang="nl-be">
  <title>EXAMPLE</title> // default by Wordpress
  <meta property="og:title" content="og:title #2"> // default by Wordpress and being used
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
                <meta name="og:image" content="/image.jpg"> // default by Wordpress
 </head> 
</html>
```

What happens is that Whatsapp and Facebook are taking the 2nd `og:title` meta tag, which doesn't make sense in my opinion.

Changing the title page in the backend is not a solution, because it becomes something like *Check out our wonderful shop!*, this is not user friendly. Also I'm not a fan of Yoast, because Yoast loads extra code into the pages, which I don't want.

Who knows a solution to this, or can explain why this is happening?

---

**Update & Answer**
Thanks to Chris I understand that og: meta tags are being scanned from top to bottom in the `<head>`, and updates the 2 identical properties with the last one that is being scanned. This RDFa process is typical for apps like Facebook, Whatsapp, Twitter. ***One exception:*** `og:image` seems to be needed in the top, it doesn't override a second or third one below it.

Google Search related tags are being picked up by the first one in the top of the `<head>` and keeps that one as "first come, first serve".

**Solution:** I will inject og: tags into the bottom of the `<head>` and the other ones will be kept in the top. Tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook and other apps generally use their own slimmed down versions of RDFa parsing, which from my understanding is a way to parse meta data from xml and html documents. From what I was reading, it seems that as the parser goes through your html page, it will add the first metadata piece it finds to it's "current subject", and if it finds another one with the same name, it will then overwrite the "current subject" with the updated info.

It seems like a pretty complicated topic, so I suppose the simple answer would just be that their parser will always take the last meta data tag and use that.

To fix the issue, I would see if you can inject your custom og:title/metadata below the one autoinjected by Wordpress.

[You can read more about RDFa parsing here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-rdfa-syntax-20081014/#s_rdfaindetail)

Comment: So you're saying it scans from top to bottom, find #1 and then find #2 in the bottom and takes that one?

Comment: Correct. The parser will create a global object, and add to and edit that object based on what it finds as it parses your html file from top to bottom. So in this case it would come across your first og:title, add that to the global object, then continue on. When it finds the 2nd og:title, it will then overwrite the first one with the 2nd one.

Comment: Okay let me test that, I will inject all the social og:tags in the bottom of the <head>.

Comment: Yes amazing! When I inject it into the bottom it's being picked up. What is strange is that Google does not work this way, Google picks up the top tags in the <head>

Comment: Is it possible that Google has a cached version of your site?

Also it seems like most of the companies like Google, Facebook, Twitter, all have their own implementation of RDFa processing, so it may be that Google implemented theirs differently from the rest.

Comment: I think Google is using a different way of RDF process. Because I inject seo meta tags for quite some time now this way, but I noticed that the og: properties were not showing correctly. So it becomes a little more coding work; Google related tags in the top and the og: tags in the bottom of the <head>. (Until they change their process).

Comment: It seems that og:image needs to be in the top, it doesn't override a second or third one below it.

Comment: That's interesting. To me it seems like there is a lot of inconsistency on functionality.